# how do I place the pygame screen in the middle?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I made a game using pygame which includes an init. 
In other ".py" file I created another init which I run from the main game.
But, the second init opened on the [0,0] place of the main init, and I want to move it.
the part that marked in a red frame at the photo, is the visual part from the second init.

i'm using Python 2.7, thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I belive what you are looking for is this: `os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'`. Put the line before you call `pygame.init()`. The line of code tries to center your window the best it can. If you wan to position the window your self, you can use this line: `os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = str(position[0]) + "," + str(position[1])` where you put the x value in the `0`'s place and the y value in the `1`'s place. For more info about pygame/SDL environment variables, see here: https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlenvvars.html.

Comment: Ok, first of by you saying `init` I assume you mean a **pygame window**. If the second window is the one your trying to center, then go into the file containing the **second** window. Before you write `pygame.init()` write `os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'` in your file with the second window. As a side note, the two windows you created are not going to be connected, if that is your thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Neither centered nor position seems to work for me, but perhaps the reason for the issue is related to the version, my first hypothesis was that the version is too new:

```
pygame 2.0.2.dev2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.9.7)
```

**update**:

My issue seems to be due to `pygame zero`. If I am just using `pygame` then the solution works nicely.

```py
import pygame

#import pgzero, pgzrun, pygame
```

Answer (score 0):

To center it properly.

Also, add the tkinter module

```
import tkinter

SCREENSIZE = tkinter.Tk()

# Get the width and height of the monitor or the screen.
width = SCREENSIZE.winfo_screenwidth()
height = SCREENSIZE.winfo_screenheight()

# This will be centered properly and my computation - it works on me.

x , y = (0.50*width)-(0.50*yourwindowwidth), 0.50*height-(0.50*yourwindowheight)

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (x,y)

# Then add the pygame window here.
```